# Can't access particular website (Macbook OSX Lion)

Tags: macos, mac, safari, google-chrome

I have one particular website (one that I'm developing) that as of today, I can't access it on **my** computer. I can access it on my phone, and other people on other computers can access it, but for some reason mine won't let me. It says "Oops, Google Chrome can't load this web page" and it gives me the option to see the cached page. Also "Safari can't connect to the server".

I've rebooted (more then once), flushed the DNS as my username, and as root, by running `dscacheutil -flushcache` and a couple of other similar commands.

I didn't run `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`.

Any ideas on what is going on and what I could do to look into the problem? Again, I can access the site just fine from other computers.

Comment: might be worth looking at your network settings to see if it has a custom DNS server set. (eg your router might be acting as a DNS server - so you might need to flush the cache from the router)

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that would be. 1) Never had that problem before and 2) the other computer used the same router, but, maybe those are legit reasons.

Comment: Just for fun did you try a restart?

Comment: Yes. More then once.

Comment: might also try creating another user account to test if it is localised to user settings

Comment: Is this site being hosted locally (i.e., on your machine)?

Comment: No. www.dropletirrigation.com . I also connected to a different Wifi, and same problem. I just set up another user which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out (with the help of someone).

It was Mamp Pro on my computer. I had a server set up as the same domain as the live website. Entered `sudo nano` state and deleted out the conflicting IP address/domain.

Comment: When you say you entered sudo nano? What do you mean? Can explain the steps you went through please because I'm having the exact same problem and it's driving me crazy

Comment: Actually it's been long enough I don't remember exactly. But the most important part was the MAMP Pro adjustment. Does editing the domain in MAMP Pro fix the problem?