# Cannot connect to specific website since OSX Mountain Lion install

Tags: macos, network, internet, web-browsing

I just installed Mountain Lion and everything is working pretty well except I can't connect to adobe.com.  I can not connect on any of the browsers (firefox, chrome, safari).  i can access the website on my other mac and my pc.

I've tried: 
Adding a New Network Location & Renew DHCP.
Changing my MTU to 1453
Clearing my SystemConfiguration of Preference Files.

I don't know what to do. I can't install the adobe suite that i just bought because I can't access the website to authenticate it.

Please please help me, im desperate.

Comment: Can you ping adobe.com and if sotraceroute to it?

Comment: There is a very low probability that this relates to your situation, but may be worth a look. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42271/cant-access-particular-website-macbook-osx-lion

Comment: If you open this on Terminal, a text file should open: "open /etc/hosts". Does yours have anything like an adobe website?

Comment: yes! when I entered that command in terminal i got "#Activation Blocker" and then a whole string of text that has adobe.com on the end of it. (ie. 127.0.0.1 hl2rcv.adobe.com,  127.0.0.1 activate-sjc0.adobe.com ) what do I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

Some 'cracked' apps change the `/etc/hosts` files so apps cannot connect to their servers to verify the credential or serials.

It looks like that could be your case.

Can you check: `sudo cat /etc/hosts` from Terminal and check if any Adobe hostname is listed there?

If so, you have installed a cracked Adobe app.

Comment: If Victoria does have a cracked app, do you have recommendations on how to find and remove it?

Comment: I bought this computer from a co-worker a few years ago.  he may have had a cracked version of adobe suite installed.  i'm not sure. There is an old version on the mac but I want to install my legit copy and it won't let me. 
I ran the command and theres a load of adobe host names that came up.  how do I get rid of them?

Comment: Sounds like this is the case; this answer should be edited to include how to remove entries from the hosts file.